# Chart, how to add data using date as xAxis

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

I'm trying to create a chart using charts plugin. I set the data and my chart doesn't show any data. I added the plugin momentjs.

```js
var chartTooltip = {
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    bodySpacing: 10,
    xPadding: 15,
    yPadding: 15,
    cornerRadius: 0.15,
    displayColors: false
};




if (document.getElementById("areaChartNoShadow")) {
    var areaChartNoShadow = document
        .getElementById("areaChartNoShadow")
        .getContext("2d");
    var myChart = new Chart(areaChartNoShadow, {
        type: "line",
        options: {
            plugins: {
                datalabels: {
                    display: false
                }
            },
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    gridLines: {
                        display: true,
                        lineWidth: 1,
                        color: "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)",
                        drawBorder: false
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        stepSize: 5,
                        min: 50,
                        max: 70,
                        padding: 0
                    }
                }],
                xAxes: [{
                    type: 'time',
                    distribution: 'linear',
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false
                    }
                }]
            },
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            tooltips: chartTooltip
        },
        data: {
            //labels: ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"],
            labels: ["2015-03-15T13:03:00Z", "2015-03-25T13:02:00Z", "2015-04-25T14:12:00Z"],
            datasets: [{
                label: "",
                //data: [54, 63, 60, 65, 60, 68, 60],
                data: [{
                        t: "2015-03-15T13:03:00Z",
                        y: 12
                    },
                    {
                        t: "2015-03-25T13:02:00Z",
                        y: 21
                    },
                    {
                        t: "2015-04-25T14:12:00Z",
                        y: 32
                    }
                ],
                pointRadius: 4,
                pointBorderWidth: 2,
                pointHoverRadius: 5,
                fill: true,
                borderWidth: 2,
            }]
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.4.0/chart.min.js"></script>


<div class="chart-container chart">
    <canvas style="padding: 25px;" id="areaChartNoShadow"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, when i change that `t` to `x` it works just fine .